# My location show on map,it is create with php language only

Tags: php

I need help,I has no idea for create php map someone help me.I need create php map to show my location.Thank you for your helps.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want? Try to be more specific. Also, we need information on your progress, what have you achieved at the moment?

Comment: My project is create php file to show user location on map.I think 2 condition need 1. create map with php or using API and show 2. open php file it is detect user location and show on map.  But i can't do how create php map using with API.Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Read docs from google maps [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple),
And after that change latitude and longitude to your location. To get it check [here](http://www.latlong.net/)

Comment: Thank you for your help.But I need to create php map show no javascript using and detect user location,not default created.

Comment: For using Google Map you must use Javascript. PHP just for back-end. If you want get user location you will use Geo Location. This is PHP for Google Map docs [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)[link]